# A woman on some kind of spider web being raped by some kind of spider alien/monster?

Tags: story-identification, movie

As a kid I remember seeing a movie, with a scene with a woman on some kind of huge (maybe electric or something) web.  Some kind of huge spider/monster/alien thing was getting ready to rape her.  Can't remember the movie though.  Any thoughts?

Comment: As a kid...when was that? Any other details, color, black and white, language...?

Comment: So, uh, i guess not that Latvian movie where the spider does rape her...

Comment: Re: @blobbymcblobby's comment - Zirneklis, a.k.a. 'Spider.'  https://www.syfy.com/syfy-wire/zirneklis-why-you-should-watch-this-latvian-movie-where-a-woman-does-it-with-a-giant-spider

Comment: @K-H-W - i know. Think I'll stick to the Giant Spider Invasion...

Answer (score 7):

It is possible that you miss remember a scene from *Krull* (1983) where Ynyr goes to ask a question of The Widow of the Web, his old girlfriend.  She gives up her control over the giant transparent spider and it comes to kill her.

Comment: Your video link has gone dead.

Comment: My first though was this movie "Krull." This movie is in dire need of a remake :)

Comment: https://youtu.be/dYow_U0S5fs?si=HuAlT_rhzOE1EEUB&t=123

Comment: @MrInfinity. Ummm. . .why? Why does EVERYTHING need a remake? What's wrong with it as it is?

Comment: Well they've been talking about it for years.  I do like the original but personally I think it'd be cool to see it with a better budget and special effects.  However, It doesn't have to be a complete remake. How about the Glaive shows up on some other planet and has a new story..